# Secure MySQL query to prevent SQL injections gives Invalid parameter number error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to secure MySQL code to prevent SQL injections so in my code below i use prepared statements and placeholders. For this reason I replaced the code:

```
return '(r.recipe_name LIKE "%' . $term . '%" OR (ri.ingredient_name IS NOT NULL AND ri.ingredient_name LIKE "%' . $term . '%"))';
```

with:

```
return '(r.recipe_name LIKE :term OR (ri.ingredient_name IS NOT NULL AND ri.ingredient_name LIKE :term))';
```

so here is my edited PHP snippet:

```
$all_text_filter = '';
$ttAll = '';

if (isset($_REQUEST['q']) && $_REQUEST['q'] != '') {
    $search_terms = array_map('trim', explode(' ', $_REQUEST['q']));
    
    $text_conditions = array_filter($search_terms, function ($term) {
        return !empty($term);
    });

    $text_conditions = array_map(function ($term) {
        return '(r.recipe_name LIKE :term OR (ri.ingredient_name IS NOT NULL AND ri.ingredient_name LIKE :term))';
    }, $text_conditions);

    if (!empty($text_conditions)) {
        $all_text_filter = ' AND (' . implode(' OR ', $text_conditions) . ')';
        $ttAll = $all_text_filter;
    }
   
}
echo "Debug: ttAll = $ttAll";

$searchText = isset($_REQUEST['q']) ? htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['q']) : '';
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $searchText);


$searchConditions = array_map(function($index, $term) {
  $paramName = ":searchTerm" . $index;
  return "r.recipe_name LIKE $paramName";
}, array_keys($searchTerms), $searchTerms);

try {

$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT r.*,
    rc.recipe_category_name,
    rc.recipe_category_slug,
    rc1.recipe_cuisine_name,
    u.name,
    u.username,
    u.photo
    FROM recipes as r
    JOIN recipe_categories as rc ON r.recipe_category_id = rc.id
    JOIN recipe_cuisines rc1 ON r.recipe_cuisine_id = rc1.id
    JOIN users u ON r.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
    WHERE r.recipe_status='Active' " . $tt1 . $tt2 . $tt3 . $tt4 . $tt5 . $tt6 . $ttAll . "
    GROUP BY r.id
    ORDER BY 
      CASE 
        WHEN " . implode(' OR ', $searchConditions) . " THEN 1 
        ELSE 2 
      END,
      r.id DESC
    LIMIT :offset, :resultsPerPage");

$q->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam(':resultsPerPage', $resultsPerPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);


// Here I bind the parameters for text conditions
  foreach ($text_conditions as $index => $termCondition) {
  $paramName = ":term" . $index;
  $q->bindValue($paramName, '%' . $termCondition . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
}


// Bind parameters for search terms
foreach ($searchTerms as $index => $term) {
    $paramName = ":searchTerm" . $index;
    $q->bindValue($paramName, '%' . $term . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);    
}



//echo $q->queryString; // Display the SQL query for debugging
$q->execute();
$res_data = $q->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  // Handle the exception, log the error, or show an error message
  echo "Error executing the query: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The problem is that now when I search for some terms eg: apple+lemon I get the error:

```
Error executing the query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

when i execute the query for example:

```
SELECT r.*, rc.recipe_category_name, rc.recipe_category_slug, rc1.recipe_cuisine_name, u.name, u.username, u.photo FROM recipes as r JOIN recipe_categories as rc ON r.recipe_category_id = rc.id JOIN recipe_cuisines rc1 ON r.recipe_cuisine_id = rc1.id JOIN users u ON r.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON r.id = ri.recipe_id WHERE r.recipe_status='Active' AND ((r.recipe_name LIKE :term OR (ri.ingredient_name IS NOT NULL AND ri.ingredient_name LIKE :term)) OR (r.recipe_name LIKE :term OR (ri.ingredient_name IS NOT NULL AND ri.ingredient_name LIKE :term))) GROUP BY r.id ORDER BY CASE WHEN r.recipe_name LIKE :searchTerm0 OR r.recipe_name LIKE :searchTerm1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, r.id DESC LIMIT :offset, :resultsPerPage
```

with the code:

```
return '(r.recipe_name LIKE "%' . $term . '%" OR (ri.ingredient_name IS NOT NULL AND ri.ingredient_name LIKE "%' . $term . '%"))';
```

Everything works fine !! I am struggling for hours to find a solution.

Comment: If you have variables like `$tt1`, `$tt2` and so on you're actually describing an array. This is way easier to wrangle than a heap of variables.

Comment: You may want to split this up into a function that composes the SQL plus the bindings, and then another that applies those and runs the query. Right now it's not easy to inspect your "plan", you just do it. Somewhere in here you're adding a placeholder but failing to bind an associated value. This mis-match would be way easier to spot if dealing with just simple data rather than a live PDO query.

Comment: You have `LIKE :term` hardcoded in the SQL code, but you're trying to bind parameters which will be `:term1`, `:term2` etc (because of `$paramName = ":term" . $index;`). Obviously this doesn't match.

Comment: General debugging tip: look at the final SQL query, after all your PHP variables have been interpolated into it. You can usually spot the mistake more quickly than staring for hours at the PHP code that builds that query.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-complicating it. Let's suppose you have a `$terms` array. Then you can do:

```
$params = [];
$criterias = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $terms; $i++) {
    $params[":term_" . $i] = "%" . $terms[$i] . "%";
    $criterias[]="(r.recipe_name LIKE :term_{$i} OR (ri.ingredient_name IS NOT NULL AND ri.ingredient_name LIKE :term_{$i}))";
}
$criteria = implode(" OR ", $criterias);
```

Make sure you add your criteria properly to the query, add any further parameters you may have and make sure you apply the parameters when you execute the query.